# RPI is discoverable via dns over eth but not over wifi

Tags: wifi, ethernet, dns

I can find my Raspberry Pi over dns when it is connected via eth, but not when it is connected over wifi. It has a static Ip adress in eth0, and a dhcp address in wifi.

I am trying to ssh into my pi, when it is connected to wifi, but it is not discoverable.

What can I do to get the Raspberry Pi make an entry in the DNS server and tell it about its hostname? So that other clients can connect to the raspberry pi via its hostname?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Does this help: [How can I resolve .local addresses in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/491747/how-can-i-resolve-local-addresses-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I'm understanding that you have created a DNS entry for the RPi's Ethernet (static IP) interface, but want the same convenience for your wifi (dhcp) interface. There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. As noted in the comments, if you are using raspbian or can add the `avahi-daemon` package, you can reference your RPi as `raspberrypi.local` (substituting the actual hostname of your RPi). This functionality is handled by `avahi-daemon` handling multicast DNS (MDNS) on the RPi itself.
2. If your DHCP server (i.e. your router) supports the feature, the DHCP server (not the RPi) can create dynamic DNS entries for addresses it hands out via DHCP. I use `dnsmasq` as my DHCP server on my router, and it supports this functionality out of the box. If my RPi named `raspberrypi` gets an address from `dnsmasq`, I can simply refer to it as `raspberrypi` (e.g. `ping raspberrypi` - no `.local` necessary).

The key point is that your hostnames are resolved by whatever is doing DNS resolution on your network. That DNS server must either create the appropriate entries separate from your RPi, or you use some other method you can control from the RPi (e.g. MDNS).

Comment: The solution is to manually add the Raspberry Pi to the DNS server (corporate windows domain). The problem is, that the Raspberry Pi is not added to the AD structure nor has it a valid account in the windows domain. Therefore, the RPI is not allowed to use DNS entries even though it can read them using ‘host -l [domain.local]’. But ‘ping [hostname]’ does not work because the RPI is not allowed to use the DNS entries in the windows domain server. Thanks for your hint,

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Yes, Windows domains typically require that the machine be added to the domain, which adds another significant layer of complexity. I hand't realized you are working in a corporate environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy one of these [OLED Displays](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/adafruit-pioled-128x32-monochrome-oled-add-on-for-raspberry-pi) which can be programmed to show the IP on boot.
If you only needed to find it once you could log onto your router and find the ip through the connected devices panel.
Hope this helps :)